# using share dialog for facebook sdk 3.5 android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

![enter image description here][1]I've been using facebook 3.0 sdk with the social-auth library in my applications to make posts  and it works fine. Now I want to upgrade to the 3.5.1 sdk so I can use the share dialog. My code is

```
        FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder mydialog = new ShareDialogBuilder(getActivity());
        if(mydialog.canPresent()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(getActivity())
            .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setName("Hello This is a Share")
            .setLink("www.gooogle.com")
            .build();

            shareDialog.present();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

and in my manifest I have added this in my application tag

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
</application>
```

In my values/strings.xml I have `<string name="app_id">000817000000323</string>`

So far this brings up the dialog and populates it but when I click share on my device it says (#404) remote_app_id doesn't match stored id.

I am positive my id is correct because I can still post using the same id and the social auth library. Is there a different way to get the app id for facebook 3.5.1?

Apparently I can't post an image yet.

And here is the code I use to get my hash key. I'm using jre6 keytool

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keyst
ore "MY_DEBUG_KEYSTORE" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1
-binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
Enter keystore password:  mypassword

MY HASH KEY WAS RETURNED (ending with an "=")
```

Comment: This usually means your key hash does not match any stored values in your Facebook's app settings. Have you updated the key hashes in your app settings? Are you signing your app with a new key?

Comment: No its the same key and I'm currently using that key to post successfully with social-auth library. Would I need to use the secret key anywhere?

Comment: No, you do not need to use the secret key. This error is specifically to do with hash keys.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try again on a new project. Just to confirm the hash key for will be same for every project on same machine?

Comment: The hash key is the same for every project as long as you use the same keystore. Depending on how your environment is set up, different computers will likely have different keystores.

Comment: Just tried with a new project and new key, same result. I must have missed some configuration. I'll edit my post and add a screen shot of my developer facebook page